# 2D Char array in Java is not updating after being changed in a method

Tags: java

So there is a two dimensional array called board that gets printed by the printBoard() method in the while loop. In the Turn() method I update an element of the array depending on the user input. If the user inputs a 1, I update the board[0][0] index with an X or an O depending on who's turn it is. When the element is changed  on line 65 or 86 depending on whose turn it is, the array that gets printed from the printBoard() method does not change?

I have tried to fix this issue on my own by making the method return the board array but I'm not sure what else to try. Can anyone tell me why the code I have sent does not function as intended and how I can fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      // Creates a board 2D array and initializes 
      // it with numbers from 1-9 for easier user input
      char[][] board = {
         {'1','2','3'},
         {'4','5','6'},
         {'7','8','9'}
      };
      
      // Creates a keyboard object to scan from
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            
      // Creates a string instead of a boolean
      // so that the variable can eventually store the player
      // that won, removing the need for another variable
      boolean gameActive = true;
      
      int turnNumber = 1;
      
      int x_input = 0;
      int o_input = 0;
      
      while (gameActive == true)
      {
         // Prints the board
         printBoard(board);
         
         // Turn function
         Turn(keyboard, turnNumber, board, x_input, o_input);
         
         // Win checker method goes here eventual
         
         // Increments the turn variable
         turnNumber++;
         
      }
      
      // Post game winner declaration goes here eventually
      
   }
   public static void Turn(Scanner keyboard, int turnNumber, char[][] board, int x_input, int o_input)
   {
      // If-else statement determines who's turn it is (Odd = X, Even = O)
      
      // If the turn number is odd, it's player X's turn
      if (turnNumber % 2 == 1)
      {
         System.out.println("Player X, please input where you would like to play: ");
         x_input = keyboard.nextInt();
         
         // Loops through the board to find a number (which means an empty spot that has not yet been played) 
         // which matches what the user input
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            { 
               // When a match has been found, the element of the array gets updated
               if (board[i][j] == (char)x_input)
               {
                  board[i][j] = 'X';
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
      }
      // If the turn number is even, it's player O's turn
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Player O, please input where you would like to play: ");
         o_input = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        // Loops through the board to find a number (which means an empty spot that has not yet been played) 
        // which matches what the user input
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            { 
               // When a match has been found, the element of the array gets updated
               if (board[i][j] == (char)o_input)
               {
                  board[i][j] = 'O';
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   public static void printBoard(char[][] board)
   {
      
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
         {
            
            if (j == 2)
            {
               System.out.println( board[i][j] + " ");
            }
            else 
            {
               System.out.print( board[i][j] + " ");
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger? What did you find?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems, I think a debugger is a good idea.

Comment: You need `x_input = keyboard.next().charAt(0);` Try to think why. Method names begin [lower case](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)
 btw. Underscores only in the names of constants or as digit separation

Comment: On a sidenote: remember to follow Java naming conventions. Methods and variables use lowerCamelCase (and no underscores), classes get to use UpperCamelCase (still no underscodes) and constants use UPPER_SNAKE_CASE. And then also remember that method names should reflect "what they do", with variable names reflecting "what they're for". So change `Turn`, which currently suggests its a class to anyone versed in Java, into `playTurn`, which anyone versed in Java will immediately know is a method, thanks to using the correct casing, and having a verb as part of its name.